# PowerShell Script to Find SharePoint List Template ID

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell

I had written the below code to ignore the statements based on if condition, But find no luck. Can any one do let me know what's wrong in my below code

```
$myListColl = $eachWeb.Lists;
$mylistsToIgnore=101
foreach ($eachList in $oListColl)
{
   if($mylistsToIgnore==$eachList.TempladID)
    {
     //Ignore statement
    }
    else 
    {
    //Other Statement
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

For starters, you compare on the wrong property (and you are not using a PowerShell compare operator):

Change

```
if($mylistsToIgnore==$eachList.TempladID)
```

to

```
if($mylistsToIgnore -eq $eachList.TemplateID)
```

Also, another typo:

Change

```
foreach ($eachList in $oListColl)
```

to

```
foreach ($eachList in $myListColl)
```

Comment: On Break point I don't get any value of   below line , But it is showing condition as right

$templateid= $eachList.TemplateID

Answer (score 3):

There is no TemplateId property in `SPList` object. You have to find it by TemplateFeatureId in `SPWeb.ListTemplates`.

```
$myListColl = $eachWeb.Lists
$mylistsToIgnore = @(101)

foreach ($eachList in $myListColl)
{
    $listTemplate = $eachWeb.ListTemplates | ? {$_.FeatureId -eq $eachList.TemplateFeatureId}
    if ($mylistsToIgnore.Contains($listTemplate.Type_Client))
    {
        # Ignore statement
    }
    else 
    {
        # Other Statement
    }
}
```